# Open Word Document Without Updating Fields

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes

We have some documents with Date fields (field code: `DATE \@ "dd MMMM yyyy"`) in our document store. When opening those documents, Word automatically updates the field to show today's date rather than the date the document was originally created from the template that has the Date field in it. (Unfortunately, the person who set this up didn't realize that would happen.)

This is confusing people like crazy, they go into a document from July and it has today's date on it. Is there a way (without writing custom code) to open a Word document *without* auto-updating its Date fields? I can see if I look directly at the document data (without word) that the field has its value from the 2nd of July stored...

Comment: You can build date fields (content controls) that remain fixed or that convert to plain text once edited.  That only helps if you're willing to edit all of your docs.  The standard date field (Alt+Shift+D) content control can't be edited with the basic tools on the Developer tab.  I'm unaware of a way to deactivate a content control when opening a doc.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the document in "protected view." That won't update the Date field.

1. Open Word
2. Open the **Open** dialog (for instance, in Word365, click **Open** in the toolbar on the left, then click **Browse**)
3. Navigate to your file
4. Click the down-arrow next to the **Open** button
5. Choose **Open in Protected View**

[image]